# Jmeter-Performance Testing Results

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing

I have done performance test using Jmeter for the below shown requirement.

Having **15 users**, **30 seconds** for ramp-up period and to schedule for **1800 seconds duration** to run the test,

```
1. To calculate the time it takes to open the URL, to provide values in all the fields and to submit it.
```

I have done this test in **INDIAN server** and got the following results,

```
1. Average response time : 23 seconds to open the URL.
2. Average response time : 88 seconds to fill the values in the URL.
3. Average response time : 10 seconds to submit.
```

But the thing is, I need to find response time for **US server** which fulfils my client's requirement. Can anyone help me in this scenario ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

So what is your problem (apart from high response times)? Just point JMeter to the US server and re-run your test.

I would recommend keeping `Server Name or IP`and `Port` blank for the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers and use [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults) to provide the endpoint server. This way you will be able to change the server from Indian to US and vice versa by amending the IP address only in one place.

I don't also like your point 2 (Average response time : 88 seconds to fill the values in the URL), JMeter acts on protocol level, it doesn't actually "types" or "fills" anything so maybe you should redesign your test like:

- Open the URL
- Submit

  - Timer (i.e. [Uniform Random Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Uniform_Random_Timer)) to simulate user filling in the form

The timer will be executed **before** the Submit request and its duration will not be included into the response time

Comment: Thanks for your response, Here in Jmeter by using webdriver sampler I used to run the script. Specifically, For that results only I mentioned the above things. Also I have tried HTTP Request and Request Defaults to know response time for US Server, but it also providing same results like INDIAN server. Client's expectations are lower response time than this.